# MySQL SQL File Strange Syntax Error in MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I have encountered strange syntax errors in my SQL file according to MySQL and Visual Studio. I have no clue of what is wrong. VS says there is syntax error in

```
"SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO""
```

with the equal sign displaying the error. Also in a create database if not exists statement, several of the words are highlighted in red denoting a syntax error.

Last, VS and MySQL claims syntax errors with the create table statements.

Please help, this is very annoying. MySQL server version 8.0.13.

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `Bible_KJV`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `Bible_KJV` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
USE `Bible_KJV`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Genesis`
--

CREATE TABLE `Genesis` (
  `chapter` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `verse` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `text` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_b

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Exodus`
--

CREATE TABLE `Exodus` (
  `chapter` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `verse` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `text` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_b
```

Here is an image with the syntax errors highlighted.
[Syntax Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEPbP.png)

Here is the syntax error I receive when importing into MySQL:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ') ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
>   COLLATE=utf8_b
>
> CREATE TABLE `Exodus`' at line 5

Comment: Please do not Summarise your error meessages. Show us ALL the erro rmessage and ALL the relevant code to go with it

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting

Comment: I dont think there is any point in trying to make a transaction here as most DDL statements force a commit, for obvious reasons

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the syntax. I tested it in my instance of MySQL 8.0.18 and it works fine up until your genuine syntax error because you have an extra comma after your `Exodus.text` column. Did you install MySQL for Visual Studio? See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html

Comment: This is just syntax highlighting in VS. What happens if you run the script in mysql?

Comment: Running the script in MySQL displays the following syntax error:
|ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_b







CREATE TABLE `Exodus`' at line 5

Comment: Yes, that's the error I spotted. Where you have `text TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
)` you should not have a comma after the DEFAULT '0' and before the `)`. In other words, the last column defined in each table should not have a comma before the closing `)` of the CREATE TABLE. This is the same rule as in English language, where we do not put a comma after the last item in a list.